# Changing css for subnav while keeping original nav with pictures

Tags: html, css

I want to change the subnavs on this code but everytime I try it takes the parent element (the background image from above.

I would have thought adding the following code would get rid of the background image for the subnavs but it doesn't.

```
 ul.subnav li { 
background-color:000; 
}
```

What I want is to do some basic css for the subnavs with the names of each link. Nothing fancy. 
Heres a link to the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/mitchelll182/t7QQ8/1/

Comment: A little advice... adding individual classes to everything is a pretty rough way of doing things and will make it difficult to work on. In regard to your question, try parent/child selectors like ".navbar2 > a " to only apply CSS to the first child, and not the dropdowns.

Comment: Took your advice and got rid of the subnavs and put in the child selector. Making some progress. Just need to figure out how to have it align below it and not within the navbar. Guessing some type of absolute position and float.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I see you're doing a CSS only menu, but that involves putting classes on everything and it ends up being a huge code mess. I think a better way would be to use jQuery. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ewB9b/

See how the HTML code is nice and clean? Just nested UL's with one class. Now in the CSS, you can easily style the main links differently from the drop-downs. Read the comments in the CSS to see what's what.

```
.
```

Comment: After so much time messing around with this menu, literally weeks, I think I will use your method. I just wanted to use a language I understood. I started learn javascript awhile back but gave up on it because i read that it takes longer to render on browsers and I had a hard time looking at the code and understanding. Guess I will go back and start the learning process. Thanks for the code I will definitely use it.

Comment: Weird, it wont show as soon as I add css let alone the java

Comment: Guessing it is because I didn't wrap it, figured this out after some research. I will need to take a crash course on java soon.

Comment: Yeah just make sure you've included jQuery 1.8, and that you use the same code from the jsfiddle. It should work! Then you'll just need to style it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ul.subnav li { 
 background-image: none;
 background-color:000; 
}
```